# Is it possible to write «я слушаю музыки» and what would be its meaning?

Tags: существительные, родительный-падеж, винительный-падеж

Usually we encounter «я слушаю музыку» (I listen to music - accusative) but would it be possible, as music is uncountable, to use the partitive-genitive: я слушаю музыки» ?

If it is possible and does not sound unnatural, what would be its meaning?

If it is not possible or would sound awkwardly unnatural, is it because of the nature of the verb “to listen” or linked to the particular nature of music (abstract uncountable) ?

Comment: Падеж зависит от глагола "слушать " (что?) музыку.

Comment: What resource would let me know what case is required by what verb ? Where can I look this up and would such a resource also let me know when a verb may be used with two or more different cases (such as ждать or хотеть) ?

Comment: Красных В. И. Русские глаголы и предикативы. Словарь сочетаемости. М., 1993.

Comment: Словарь сочетаемости слов русского языка / Под ред. П. Н. Денисова, В. В. Морковкина. М., 1978; 2-е изд., испр. и доп. М., 1983; 3-е изд., испр. М., 2002. (

Comment: http://dict.ruslang.ru/abstr_noun.php?act=search&noun=%CC%F3%E7%FB%EA%E0&adj=&verb=&base=&semclass=&subclass=&mood=&phase=&good=&size=&neg=&order=

Comment: Phrase "я слушаю музыки много" is absolutely normal.

Comment: Here the case depends on the много, not on the verb, and много, мало require genitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«Я слушаю музыки» sounds just wrong. I can't see it being used in a meaningful way.

The partitive genitive goes well with **по-** verbs: попить чаю, поесть плюшек... (to drink tea for a bit, to have a few rolls...) But even then, «послушать музыки» doesn't sound quite right. I would say «послушать музыку» or «послушать немного музыки» to mean 'to listen to some music for a bit'.

You could say «наслушаться музыки» 'to listen to too much music'. It looks like a partitive genitive but I'm not sure what it actually is.

Answer (score 3):

Падеж зависит от глагола "слушать " (что?) музыку.

What resource would let me know what case is required by what verb ? Where can I look this up and would such a resource also let me know when a verb may be used with two or more different cases (such as ждать or хотеть) ? –

There are several dictionaries of collocations:

Красных В. И. Русские глаголы и предикативы. Словарь сочетаемости. М., 1993.

Словарь сочетаемости слов русского языка / Под ред. П. Н. Денисова, В. В. Морковкина. М., 1978; 2-е изд., испр. и доп. М., 1983; 3-е изд., испр. М., 2002. ( –
The following one is an online dictionary

dict.ruslang.ru/… –

The last one you can try now. Just put the word музыка (существительное) and press поиск. You will find all the results below on the left.

Some more:

Лебедева М.Н. Словарь-справочник синтаксической сочетаемости глаголов: глагольное управление и другие связи глагола [ 2500 лексических единиц]. 3-е изд. М. : Русский язык. Курсы, 2006. 192 с. [1-е изд. в 2000 г.].

Малышев ГЛ. Глагол всему голова: учебный словарь русских глаголов и глагольного управления для иностранцев. СПб. : Златоуст. Вып. 1: Базовый уровень. 2005. 144 с.; Вып. 2: Первый сертификационный уровень. 2006. 448 с.